# Sum of two squares in a $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

I need to show that every element in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ can be written as a sum of two squares. The case $p=2$ is trivial and $0$ is always $0^2 + 0^2$. So all I have to do is show that every element of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ (the group of units) can be expressed as a sum of two squares. The question hints that I should consider the set of elements of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ expressible as a sum of two squares.

Associativity is trivial, the identity element $1 = 1^2 + 0^2$ exists.
Closure holds by the identity $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2$.
I don't know how to show that inverses exist.

Answer (score 4):

For finite groups, to show that a subset is a subgroup if you check closure and non-emptyness you don't need to check inverses because each element has finite order: $g^{-1} = g^{o(g) - 1}$ is in the subset by closure assumption.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I feel so stupid now!

Comment: But why would this prove that the sums of two squares fill up all of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Also, $0$ is a sum of two squares, and it has no inverse, so ...

Answer (score 2):

The following is another version of the argument by Jyrki Lahtonen. Beside the numbers $1,2,\dots, p-1$ write QR for quadratic residue and NR for quadratic non-residue. So we write QR beside $1$.

Note that we write each of QR and NR $\frac{p-1}{2}$ times. So at some time, QR is followed by NR. This means there is a NR $c$ which is congruent to $a^2+1^2$ modulo $p$. But as $x$ ranges over the numbers from $1$ to $p-1$, $x^2 c$ ranges over the non-residues. So the non-residues can be written as $(xa)^2+x^2$.